# Javascript - new Date() returns wrong timezone on Android 7.0 device

Tags: javascript, android, date, datetime

The following issue appears only on devices with Android 7.0 (haven't checked on 7.0 +).

When the time zone is changed on the device, the system date changes correctly but new Date() gives the time zone which was set earlier.

Ex:

**Time zone selected** : GMT +05:30(Indian Standard Time)

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);// Thu Mar 16 2017 14:31:51 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

**Change Time zone :**

**Time zone selected** : GMT +01:00 (Central European Standard Time).
System time changes on the device.

But new date still gives the previously selected time zone.

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);// Thu Mar 16 2017 14:40:32 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

**The timezone doesn't change.**

If I restart the device, new Date then gives the correct timezone.

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);// Thu Mar 16 2017 10:21:12 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Has anyone faced this issue ? 
Is there any workaround / solution ?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Yes. Edited the post.

Comment: How so? Restarting the device is not really acceptable. Does anyone know if this issue is affecting later versions of Android, i.e. have they fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same issue so I told my code to get the time from my server from a php file :

```
    <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
echo date("c");
?>
```

Then jQuery :

```
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "time.php",
    success: function(phptime)
    {
    var now = new Date(phptime);
    var hours = addZero(now.getHours());
    var minutes = addZero(now.getMinutes());
    var dayIndex = now.getDay();
    console.log(phptime);
    console.log(now);
    console.log(hours);
    console.log(minutes);
    console.log(dayIndex);
            }
    });
```

So now my time doesn't depend on the device but only on the server.

Comment: This is not an answer, if the app wants to display local time